# Visual studios connection gets disconnected with iOS

Tags: iphone, xamarin, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-mac

When I try to run my xamarin.iOS project in some devices it says .. *upload succeeded* and app get disconnected from visual studio but my expectation is I should be able to debug the app from visual studio.

This doesn't happen with all devices.

I verified there is no code signer or provisioning profile problem with these devices.

Any ideas on how to solve this issue (I am using visual studio 2017 for mac )

Comment: Did these devices which failed to debug have low memory? Will them work fine when use them to debug with Xcode for objective-c/swift project?

Comment: @Kevin - I don't know ..I am using xamarin.. I tried restarting the device... then also things are same so .. I don't think its memory issue

Comment: Product issues like this can be reported to Microsoft via Help | Report a Problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Clear the temp files
- Restart the mac

solved